# Oracle - DB Appears to Breaking Up JDBC Batch Insert

Tags: java, oracle, etl, oracle12c

We're hitting an odd issue with one of our ETL applications. Effectively, the process opens a cursor to pull data from one DB, performs some transformations, and then inserts to another DB using batch inserts.

For all tables in the ETL, our commit interval is set to 1000 rows. So after reading in each chunk of 1k rows and performing transformations, we do a single batch insert to the target DB (using Java, Spring Batch, OJDBC7 v12.1.0.2).

However, some tables are brutally slow. We first made sure FKs were off (they are). We then checked to make sure triggers were disabled (they are). We added logging to get the rows in each batch insert (it was 1000 except for the final insert of each thread).

Finally, querying `v$sql`, it appears that for some tables we're seeing near to 1000 rows/execution, which we'd expect. However, for the painful tables, it's often hovering closer to **one**! We'd expect most tables to be a bit in the high 900s since the final commit for the thread might not have a full 1k rows, but the extraordinarily low rows per execution on some tables is a real head scratcher.

Some wide tables (100+ columns) are problematic, but others are fine. Some highly partitioned (100+ partitions) tables are slow, but others are fine. So I'm very confused. Has anyone seen this before? I'm running out of ideas!

Thanks!

Here's what we were seeing in `v$sql` (table names obfuscated):

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR (sql_text, 'Insert into [^\(]*') sql_text,
    sql_id,
    TRUNC(
    CASE
      WHEN SUM (executions) > 0
      THEN SUM (rows_processed) / SUM (executions)
    END,2) rows_per_execution
  FROM v$sql
  WHERE parsing_schema_name = 'PFT010_RAPP_PRO'
  AND sql_text LIKE 'Insert into%'
  GROUP BY sql_text,
    sql_id
  )
ORDER BY rows_per_execution ASC;

SQL_STATEMENT                                   SQL_ID         ROWS_PER_EXECUTION
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Insert into C__PFT010.S_T___V_R_L_A_            agwu1dd1wr2ux     1.04
Insert into C__PFT010.S_T___G_L_A___T_          7ymw7jtdd9g53     1.25
Insert into C__PFT010.S_T___F_L_A_              7cynt9fmtpz83     1.44
Insert into C__PFT010.S_T___Q_L_A___A_          27v3fuj028cy6     1.57
Insert into C__PFT010.S_T___E_R_P_Y_A_P_S_A_    2t544j11a286z     1.80
Insert into C__PFT010.S_T___I_S_R_              anu8aac070sut     1.84
Insert into C__PFT010.S_T___R_C_R___T_T_        0ydz33s6guvcn     2.05
Insert into C__PFT010.S_T_R___D_R_P_Y_A_P_      7y76r10dmzqvh     2.14
Insert into C__PFT010.S_T___S_L_A___Y_T_S_S_    d7136fg9w033w     2.25
Insert into C__PFT010.S_T___R_C_R___T_T_        2pswt3cmp48s4     2.31
Insert into C__PFT010.S_T___F_R_P_Y_A_P_S_P_    170c7v23yyrms     2.46
Insert into C__PFT010.C_M_N_C___R_S_            fw3wbt4p08kx4     2.66
Insert into C__PFT010.T_A_H_N_T___E_A_Y_        dk5rwm58qqy8b     2.68
Insert into C__PFT010.O_G_L_A___N_O_            gtd4azc32gku4     3.05
Insert into C__PFT010.N_L_S_D___I_B_S_G_        a1a01vthwf2yk     3.15
Insert into C__PFT010.S_T___Q_L_A___A_          7ac6dqwb1jfyh     3.56
Insert into C__PFT010.S_T___J_P_M___A_A_        8n5z68bgkuan1     3.88
Insert into C__PFT010.S_T_R___F_R_P_Y_A_P_S_P   1r62s9qgjucy8     4.25
Insert into C__PFT010.L_A___W_E_S_I_            19rxcmgvct74c     4.28
Insert into C__PFT010.C___U___T_D_T_P_          fdzfdbpdzd18c     4.40
Insert into C__PFT010.S_T_R___U_T_A_S_E_        gs6z5szk9x1n2     4.61
Insert into C__PFT010.S_T_R___H_S_B_I_Y_L_S_    0zsz69pa3ahga     6.58
Insert into C__PFT010.C___F___U_R_P_T_          13xgutdszxab1     8.00
Insert into C__PFT010.S_T_R___J_P_M___A_A_      355gqx1sspdr0    20.19
Insert into C__PFT010.C___D___O___V_            4dmu2bqrra0fg    22.40
Insert into C__PFT010.S_T_R___Q_L_A___A_        dsx0nsrxkz5cf    36.14
Insert into C__PFT010.S_T___V_R_L_A___E_R_      2urs0mbjn3nm2   126.96
Insert into C__PFT010.S_S_C_S___E_A_L_S_G_      awq4fzkk3rsww   179.48
Insert into C__PFT010.S_S_D_S___C_I_I_Y_S_G_    7hpw0kv2z5nsh   417.87
Insert into C__PFT010.S_T_R___D_P_S___M_I_      cjgdmgfznapdk   502.36
Insert into C__PFT010.C___F___E_                6hv4smzmm4hx8   531.00
Insert into C__PFT010.N_L_S_E_R___R_            61zu9j25kgn2u   533.50
Insert into C__PFT010.S_T___B_P_S___A_T_R_      31xpaj7afk054   714.94
Insert into C__PFT010.S_T_R___C_L_A___O_G_V_    dx4mna12hdh9c   749.66
Insert into C__PFT010.S_T___C_P_S___D_R_S_      b7z4y1mruk714   784.56
Insert into C__PFT010.S_T___S_L_A___Y_T_S_S_    29qbqkzhmt83h   792.63
Insert into C__PFT010.A_H_C_R_T_                c6kmyt3a410ch   801.67
Insert into C__PFT010.S_T___X_P_S___H_N_        g6cbtus4bccm8   826.19
Insert into C__PFT010.S_T___K_R_B_T___T_T_      0xps4ddmw322h   873.36
Insert into C__PFT010.C___O___C_L___M_          fz91ju8jw22yc   928.90
Insert into C__PFT010.S_T___H_L_A___T_T_        44rh8722j51fm   982.16
Insert into C__PFT010.C___C_L_S_C_R_T_          4vpnstj8qxy80   991.75
Insert into C__PFT010.S_T___P_L_A___E_U_D_      fgunfbpddf2af   994.50
Insert into C__PFT010.S_T___A_S___I___O_S_      0d0x5ymp2y248   996.09
Insert into C__PFT010.S_T___K_R_B_T___T_T_      61rmgzvqrbudh   999.25
Insert into C__PFT010.S_T___D_P_S___M_I_        bu3hc03yugc8h   999.88
Insert into C__PFT010.L___R_E___E_L_R_C_P_2_00  bvrxzq2v3npc6   999.91
Insert into C__PFT010.N_L_S_G_A_T_S_N___R_C     7sj2ydm7m2z6u   999.96
Insert into C__PFT010.S_T___V_R_L_A___E_E_E     8n6nbsjfpvu70   999.98
Insert into C__PFT010.S_T___L_I_T_B_N_F_T       5b89j9um2jkuu   999.98
Insert into C__PFT010.S_T___D_P_S___M_I_        906jnw4jarsxk   999.98
Insert into C__PFT010.S_T___T_E_R_M_T           9a8vnhnbp5jpn  1000.00
```

**Update:** the data is a bit stale at this point (all the fast threads have completed), but here are some counts with SQL IDs, Execution Counts, and Rows/Execution. All these tables have (or will have) tens of millions of rows

```
SQL ID          Executions  Rows/Execution
agwu1dd1wr2ux   118043      1.04
anu8aac070sut   194768      1.84
dr8qxkcx1xybj   11635084    1.85
a37vqfjqcyd3j   4939754     2.36
8n5z68bgkuan1   2642091     3.95
4sps6y4bkkr6p   268739      13.77
5tdhpn96vpz6d   240227      166.85
```

---

**Additional SQL Trace Data...:**

*Here's an insert for a table that's working nicely*

```
PARSING IN CURSOR #139935830739792 len=315 dep=0 uid=845 oct=2 lid=845 tim=2116001679604 hv=581690290 ad='c168de130' sqlid='906jnw4jarsxk'
Insert into ___PFT010.S_T__A__P_S__E_A_L
 (A_A_D_ID, CREATE_DTM, DOC_TXN_ID, EFF_DT, EFF_END_DT, EFF_START_DT, EXTRACT_DT, G_O__A_D__F_G, MAINT_DTM, MAINT_USERID, P_R_O__E_A_L, P_R_O__R_L_, R_C_RD_T_P, S__ID, S_R_I_E__ID )
 values (:1 , :2 , :3 , :4 , :5 , :6 , :7 , :8 , :9 , :10 , :11 , :12 , :13 , :14 , :15  )
END OF STMT
PARSE #139935830739792:c=0,e=25,p=0,cr=0,cu=0,mis=0,r=0,dep=0,og=1,plh=0,tim=2116001679603
WAIT #139935830739792: nam='SQL*Net more data from client' ela= 72 driver id=675562835 #bytes=3 p3=0 obj#=-1 tim=2116001679871
WAIT #139935830739792: nam='db file sequential read' ela= 551 file#=99 block#=78343664 blocks=1 obj#=1255124 tim=2116001680643
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
* * * a bunch more of these
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
WAIT #139935830739792: nam='db file sequential read' ela= 750 file#=99 block#=66416561 blocks=1 obj#=1255124 tim=2116001788121
WAIT #139935830739792: nam='db file sequential read' ela= 176 file#=99 block#=45513746 blocks=1 obj#=1255124 tim=2116001787117
WAIT #139935830739792: nam='db file sequential read' ela= 750 file#=99 block#=66416561 blocks=1 obj#=1255124 tim=2116001788121
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
* * * r=1000, indicating 1000 rows were written 
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
EXEC #139935830739792:c=57991,e=109295,p=131,cr=69,cu=3313,mis=0,r=1000,dep=0,og=1,plh=0,tim=2116001788944
STAT #139935830739792 id=1 cnt=0 pid=0 pos=1 obj=0 op='LOAD TABLE CONVENTIONAL  SAT1_AD_PRSN_EMAIL (cr=69 pr=131 pw=0 time=109260 us)'
XCTEND rlbk=0, rd_only=0, tim=2116001789025
CLOSE #139935830739792:c=0,e=12,dep=0,type=1,tim=2116016169474
```

*Here's one that is being annoying. This time, it only gets 1 row in the execution*

```
PARSING IN CURSOR #139935830737584 len=520 dep=0 uid=845 oct=2 lid=845 tim=2116016176184 hv=1904916192 ad='97e96dc98' sqlid='355gqx1sspdr0'
Insert into ___PFT010.S_TE_R_BJ_P_M__D_T_
 (A_A_D_ID, CREATE_DTM, DOC_TXN_ID, EFF_END_DT, EFF_START_DT, ERR_CD, ERR_FIELD, EXTRACT_DT, MAINT_USERID, P_M__A_R_I_T_A_T, P_M__A_T, P_M__C_P_I_T_A_T, P_M__C_T_H_P_AMT, P_M__E_F_DT, P_M__N_G_A_R__A_T, P_M__N_N_C_P_I_T_A_T, P_M__O_T_F_E_A_T, P_M__P_I_B_L_A_T, P_M__T_P, R_C_RD_T_P, S__ID, S_R_I_E__ID, T_A_S_I__D_, Z_R__P_M__I_D )
 values (:1 , :2 , :3 , :4 , :5 , :6 , :7 , :8 , :9 , :10 , :11 , :12 , :13 , :14 , :15 , :16 , :17 , :18 , :19 , :20 , :21 , :22 , :23 , :24  )
END OF STMT
PARSE #139935830737584:c=0,e=62,p=0,cr=0,cu=0,mis=0,r=0,dep=0,og=1,plh=0,tim=2116016176183
PARSE #139935830738688:c=0,e=14,p=0,cr=0,cu=0,mis=0,r=0,dep=1,og=4,plh=140787661,tim=2116016176703
EXEC #139935830738688:c=0,e=49,p=0,cr=0,cu=0,mis=0,r=0,dep=1,og=4,plh=140787661,tim=2116016176780
FETCH #139935830738688:c=0,e=38,p=0,cr=3,cu=0,mis=0,r=0,dep=1,og=4,plh=140787661,tim=2116016176837
CLOSE #139935830738688:c=0,e=4,dep=1,type=3,tim=2116016176862
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
* * * r=1, indicating only 1 row affected by execution
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *     
EXEC #139935830737584:c=999,e=1065,p=0,cr=4,cu=5,mis=1,r=1,dep=0,og=1,plh=0,tim=2116016177301
STAT #139935830737584 id=1 cnt=0 pid=0 pos=1 obj=0 op='LOAD TABLE CONVENTIONAL  SATERR_BJ_PYMT_DATA (cr=1 pr=0 pw=0 time=50 us)'
XCTEND rlbk=0, rd_only=0, tim=2116016177362
WAIT #139935830737584: nam='log file sync' ela= 396 buffer#=92400 sync scn=2454467328 p3=0 obj#=-1 tim=2116016177846
WAIT #139935830737584: nam='SQL*Net message to client' ela= 0 driver id=675562835 #bytes=1 p3=0 obj#=-1 tim=2116016177877
WAIT #139935830737584: nam='SQL*Net message from client' ela= 1045 driver id=675562835 #bytes=1 p3=0 obj#=-1 tim=2116016178938
CLOSE #139935830737584:c=0,e=4,dep=0,type=0,tim=2116016178981
```

*Here's the same table, with 34 rows instead of 1. The fact that it's inconsistent is what's annoying me the most*

```
PARSING IN CURSOR #139935830737584 len=520 dep=0 uid=845 oct=2 lid=845 tim=2116016169849 hv=1904916192 ad='97e96dc98' sqlid='355gqx1sspdr0'
Insert into ___PFT010.S_TE_R_BJ_P_M__D_T_
 (A_A_D_ID, CREATE_DTM, DOC_TXN_ID, EFF_END_DT, EFF_START_DT, ERR_CD, ERR_FIELD, EXTRACT_DT, MAINT_USERID, P_M__A_R_I_T_A_T, P_M__A_T, P_M__C_P_I_T_A_T, P_M__C_T_H_P_AMT, P_M__E_F_DT, P_M__N_G_A_R__A_T, P_M__N_N_C_P_I_T_A_T, P_M__O_T_F_E_A_T, P_M__P_I_B_L_A_T, P_M__T_P, R_C_RD_T_P, S__ID, S_R_I_E__ID, T_A_S_I__D_, Z_R__P_M__I_D )
 values (:1 , :2 , :3 , :4 , :5 , :6 , :7 , :8 , :9 , :10 , :11 , :12 , :13 , :14 , :15 , :16 , :17 , :18 , :19 , :20 , :21 , :22 , :23 , :24  )
END OF STMT
PARSE #139935830737584:c=0,e=326,p=0,cr=0,cu=0,mis=1,r=0,dep=0,og=1,plh=0,tim=2116016169848
PARSE #139935830738688:c=0,e=19,p=0,cr=0,cu=0,mis=0,r=0,dep=1,og=4,plh=140787661,tim=2116016170242
EXEC #139935830738688:c=0,e=59,p=0,cr=0,cu=0,mis=0,r=0,dep=1,og=4,plh=140787661,tim=2116016170329
FETCH #139935830738688:c=0,e=44,p=0,cr=3,cu=0,mis=0,r=0,dep=1,og=4,plh=140787661,tim=2116016170393
CLOSE #139935830738688:c=0,e=3,dep=1,type=3,tim=2116016170421
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
* * * r=34, indicating only 34 row affected by execution. WHAT IS HAPPENING?!?!
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *     
EXEC #139935830737584:c=5000,e=4592,p=0,cr=11,cu=48,mis=1,r=34,dep=0,og=1,plh=0,tim=2116016174513
STAT #139935830737584 id=1 cnt=0 pid=0 pos=1 obj=0 op='LOAD TABLE CONVENTIONAL  SATERR_BJ_PYMT_DATA (cr=8 pr=0 pw=0 time=3648 us)'
XCTEND rlbk=0, rd_only=0, tim=2116016174622
WAIT #139935830737584: nam='log file sync' ela= 684 buffer#=92313 sync scn=2454467326 p3=0 obj#=-1 tim=2116016175452
WAIT #139935830737584: nam='SQL*Net message to client' ela= 1 driver id=675562835 #bytes=1 p3=0 obj#=-1 tim=2116016175551
WAIT #139935830737584: nam='SQL*Net message from client' ela= 481 driver id=675562835 #bytes=1 p3=0 obj#=-1 tim=2116016176058
CLOSE #139935830737584:c=0,e=6,dep=0,type=0,tim=2116016176107
```

Comment: Can you include the number of executions in your v$sql query output.

Comment: @BobC added some, but the other data has rolled off the `v@sql` table since they completed

Comment: This may be obvious, but have you checked you code? I know you are saying that the majority of your inserts of 1000 rows, but do you have logs/instrumentation to confirm that?

Comment: @BobC That was the logging we confirmed as I mentioned above. The out-of-the-box Spring Batch writer (`JdbcBatchItemWriter`) logs at debug the # of rows being inserted by the `PreparedStatement`'s `executeBatch()` call. I don't think either Spring or the Oracle trace logs are lying. Perhaps a JDBC driver issue?

Comment: Saw some other post that suggested auto-commit could play a factor with the way JDBC handles `executeBatch()`. We tried it both on and off with no change to rows per execution.

Comment: There *is* a memory constraint with the batch call; though I suspect that this is not the issue unless you have very wide rows...

Comment: It's affecting tables that aren't that wide (e.g. 33 cols, sum(data_length)=1354). I believe it stems from how JDBC his handling null bind variables when something a particular column bind value flips from populated to null or vice versa.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162845/discussion-between-bobc-and-dean-clark).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, this was a fun one, and this answer unfortunately only solves 99% of the problem...

First, we determined by looking at the bind variables that parameter type we were binding was flipping around, and each time that happened, we'd execute the prior statement and parse a new one (despite only issuing a single `executeBatch()` command from our `PreparedStatement`). So, we ended up seeing this in the trace logs:

```
Row #  Bind :1         Bind :2         Bind :3         Bind :4         Bind :5         
-----  --------------  --------------  --------------  --------------  --------------  
--parse--
    1  VARCHAR2(128)   NUMBER          TIMESTAMP       CLOB            VARCHAR2(2000)
    2  VARCHAR2(128)   NUMBER          TIMESTAMP       CLOB            VARCHAR2(2000)
    3  VARCHAR2(128)   NUMBER          TIMESTAMP       CLOB            VARCHAR2(2000)
    4  VARCHAR2(128)   NUMBER          TIMESTAMP       CLOB            VARCHAR2(2000)
--execute & parse--
    5  VARCHAR2(128)   VARCHAR2(32)    TIMESTAMP       CLOB            VARCHAR2(2000)
--execute & parse--
    6  VARCHAR2(128)   NUMBER          TIMESTAMP       VARCHAR2(32)    VARCHAR2(2000)
--execute & parse--
    7  VARCHAR2(128)   NUMBER          TIMESTAMP       CLOB            VARCHAR2(2000)
    8  VARCHAR2(128)   NUMBER          TIMESTAMP       CLOB            VARCHAR2(2000)
    9  VARCHAR2(128)   NUMBER          TIMESTAMP       CLOB            VARCHAR2(2000)
   10  VARCHAR2(128)   NUMBER          TIMESTAMP       CLOB            VARCHAR2(2000)
--execute & parse--
   11  VARCHAR2(2000)  NUMBER          VARCHAR2(32)    CLOB            VARCHAR2(2000)
--execute & parse--
   12  VARCHAR2(2000)  NUMBER          TIMESTAMP       CLOB            VARCHAR2(2000)
   13  VARCHAR2(2000)  NUMBER          TIMESTAMP       CLOB            VARCHAR2(2000)
--execute--
```

With a bit more digging, we determined that JDBC couldn't auto-determine the data type of `null` objects for us the way it could with non-null values. When a column was consistent (always null or always populated) it wasn't a problem, but when there was variability in the data, it was brutal.

Since we were loading from files, we didn't have the source data type, but luckily we DID have the ability to get the target data type (which should match), so we were able to specify that as we set each parameter on the `PreparedStatement`.

That change made some major improvements, but we still ended up seeing the following:

```
Row #  Bind :1         Bind :2         Bind :3         Bind :4         Bind :5         
-----  --------------  --------------  --------------  --------------  --------------  
--parse--
    1  VARCHAR2(128)   NUMBER          TIMESTAMP       CLOB            VARCHAR2(2000)
    2  VARCHAR2(128)   NUMBER          TIMESTAMP       CLOB            VARCHAR2(2000)
    3  VARCHAR2(128)   NUMBER          TIMESTAMP       CLOB            VARCHAR2(2000)
    4  VARCHAR2(128)   NUMBER          TIMESTAMP       CLOB            VARCHAR2(2000)
    5  VARCHAR2(128)   NUMBER          TIMESTAMP       CLOB            VARCHAR2(2000)
--execute & parse--
    6  VARCHAR2(128)   NUMBER          TIMESTAMP       VARCHAR2(32)    VARCHAR2(2000)
--execute & parse--
    7  VARCHAR2(128)   NUMBER          TIMESTAMP       CLOB            VARCHAR2(2000)
    8  VARCHAR2(128)   NUMBER          TIMESTAMP       CLOB            VARCHAR2(2000)
    9  VARCHAR2(128)   NUMBER          TIMESTAMP       CLOB            VARCHAR2(2000)
   10  VARCHAR2(128)   NUMBER          TIMESTAMP       CLOB            VARCHAR2(2000)
--execute & parse--
   11  VARCHAR2(2000)  NUMBER          TIMESTAMP       CLOB            VARCHAR2(2000)
   12  VARCHAR2(2000)  NUMBER          TIMESTAMP       CLOB            VARCHAR2(2000)
   13  VARCHAR2(2000)  NUMBER          TIMESTAMP       CLOB            VARCHAR2(2000)
--execute--
```

Definitely an improvement, but we didn't fix `CLOB`, and we saw the size `VARCHAR2` expand sometimes. After a bit more research, we stumbled across [this thread about High Version Count due to bind_mismatch](https://community.oracle.com/thread/4085383), which sounded promising. Tables where our data was nice and consistent hummed along without issue, but fields of varying length like email addresses would wreak havoc on performance. So we ran the following to force the `VARCHAR2` binds to a size of 4000:

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET EVENTS '10503 trace name context forever, level 2001';
```

After that, we tried again and got the following:

```
Row #  Bind :1         Bind :2         Bind :3         Bind :4         Bind :5         
-----  --------------  --------------  --------------  --------------  --------------  
--parse--
    1  VARCHAR2(40000) NUMBER          TIMESTAMP       CLOB            VARCHAR2(4000)
    2  VARCHAR2(40000) NUMBER          TIMESTAMP       CLOB            VARCHAR2(4000)
    3  VARCHAR2(40000) NUMBER          TIMESTAMP       CLOB            VARCHAR2(4000)
    4  VARCHAR2(40000) NUMBER          TIMESTAMP       CLOB            VARCHAR2(4000)
    5  VARCHAR2(40000) NUMBER          TIMESTAMP       CLOB            VARCHAR2(4000)
--execute & parse--                                                             
    6  VARCHAR2(40000) NUMBER          TIMESTAMP       VARCHAR2(32)    VARCHAR2(4000)
--execute & parse--                                                             
    7  VARCHAR2(40000) NUMBER          TIMESTAMP       CLOB            VARCHAR2(4000)
    8  VARCHAR2(40000) NUMBER          TIMESTAMP       CLOB            VARCHAR2(4000)
    9  VARCHAR2(40000) NUMBER          TIMESTAMP       CLOB            VARCHAR2(4000)
   10  VARCHAR2(40000) NUMBER          TIMESTAMP       CLOB            VARCHAR2(4000)
   11  VARCHAR2(40000) NUMBER          TIMESTAMP       CLOB            VARCHAR2(4000)
   12  VARCHAR2(40000) NUMBER          TIMESTAMP       CLOB            VARCHAR2(4000)
   13  VARCHAR2(40000) NUMBER          TIMESTAMP       CLOB            VARCHAR2(4000)
--execute--
```

We're now almost perfect, but we can't figure out how to prevent JDBC from binding `VARCHAR2` when we get a null `CLOB`. Luckily, we only have a couple tables with nullable `CLOB` columns, so we've dramatically improved performance and diminished the impact of the changing bind. But there's definitely a part of me that would like to get that last 1%... any suggestions?